# AWS CloudFormation Fn::Join - escape double quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, escaping, aws-cloudformation, double-quotes

I have the following code: (I have simplified the actual problem for brevity)

```
Fn::Join:
      - ""
      - - "[ {\"Key1\": \"A\""
        - "}]"
```

The result is coming out with out the double quote being escaped. 
The result is:

```
"[ {\"Key1\": \"A\"}]"
```

If I remove the backslashes, I get an error that it is not a well formed YML.

Am i missing something?

On John's comment I tried with single quotes:

```
Fn::Join:
      - ""
      - - '[ {"Key1": "A"'
        - "}]"
```

This results in:

```
[ {\"Key1\": \"A\"} ]
```

So the single quotes appear to result in insertion of back slashes.

Comment: Where does it show that? Are you sure it's not just printing it out as an escaped string?

Comment: I am storing the data in DynamoDB table. That is how it shows up in the DB table.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fn::Join documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) shows this example:

```
!Join
  - ''
  - - 'arn:'
    - !Ref Partition
    - ':s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*-'
    - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
```

So, try using single quotes to avoid the need to escape double-quotes.

Comment: I have tried that too. It seems to insert the back slashes.

Comment: There should be no need for backslashes. Just use: `-  '[{"Key1": "A"}]'`

Comment: I used exactly that. And it shows up as: [ {\"Key1\": \"A\"} ]

Comment: XML allows single OR double quotes. So can you try `"[{'Key1': 'A'}]"`?

Comment: YAML also allows strings to be unquoted, so you could just use [{'Key1': 'A'}]`

Comment: your answer works. I was doing (mistakenly) something else in the code before the final output. The single quotes do work. Thanks!